# How to reference a fixed sheet name in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I am doing reports from a set of data in Google Spreadsheet. As of now, I have several sheets, among them `Raw Data` and `Processed Data`.

In my `Processed Data` sheet, I use formulas such as: `SUM('Raw Data'!A:A)`. However, if I rename the `Raw Data` sheet to `Raw Data (old)`, all my formulas are changed to `SUM('Raw Data (old)'!A:A)`.

While I find this a really nice feature, I was wondering if there was a way to force spreadsheet to reference the sheet named `Raw Data`, in a similar fashion `$` works for cells, so that I can import my new data weekly and simply rename the newly imported sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the formula added by Brian Bennet works, it takes a significant amount of time to update and feels somewhat clunky in an arrayformula.

Instead, I used `INDIRECT` to solve my problem :

```
                 A                  |       B        |   C
 ------------------------------------------------------------
1| =SUM(INDIRECT("'Raw Data'!A:A")) |                |
2| =SUM(INDIRECT(B2&"A:A"))         | ="'Raw Data'!" |
3|                                  |                |
```

On the column `A` of this example, A1 is what I used for quick formulas, and A2 allowed for more modularity

However, as I used this formula inside `ARRAYFORMULA`, the refresh time of the array became erratic, especially when the sheet doesn't exist at first.

When the sheet doesn't exist, all cells in the arrayformula are marked `#N/A`. When I add the sheet `Raw Data`, even if I refresh my page with F5 several times, I still got the `#N/A`. I am unsure how to force the refresh. A few minutes afterwards however, the data is updated, and I can edit my sheet & the arrayformula is calculated instantly (calculation time is only very slightly impacted).

This might be another issue not necessarily related to my initial question, but I thought I should mention this behavior anyway.

As a side note : this fix doesn't work for pivot tables. I am still looking for a solution for that case.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like the `=importrange()` function in Google Sheets because the referenced sheet in that formula doesn't change.

The formula needs two things - a Spreadsheet Key, which is specific to the entire workbook, and a range to import.

The Spreadsheet Key is in the URL:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SPREADSHEET KEY HERE/edit#gid=1042908258`

Then, for the range, pick whatever range of cells you want to pull in from the `raw` sheet in the book.

A sample could be:
`=importrange("SPREADSHEET KEY", "Raw!A1:A")`

That formula will pull data from Column A as long as the sheet is called "Raw". This formula will not change when you rename a sheet in the book because it doesn't matter *which* sheet is named "Raw", it just looks for one.

Comment: As a side note, on the new Google Sheets, you have to put the whole URL : `=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SPREADSHEET KEY HERE", "Raw!A1:A")`

Comment: If they're within the same workbook, you can use the key. [The docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) also only list the key as the required data. New sheets just ask for explicit permission to pull the data once you use the formula.